# Android Fragments реализация onClickListnera через интерфейс

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-on-click, android-interface

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующую функциональность
есть `Android Activity`, которая создает два элемента `Fragment`. Нужно чтобы один из `Fragment` передавал `Activity` информацию о нажатии кнопки. 
В документации говорится, что обращение `Fragment to Activity` необходимо реализовывать через интерфейс обратного вызова, но во всех найденных примерах создается (и передается в интерфейс) слушатель для `ListFragment` (с ним проблем нет), а мне нужно реализовать слушатель для обычного `Fragment`, в котором есть две кнопки.

Что именно я делаю:

- создаю фрагмент
- реализую в нем интерфейс

  ```
  static interface onButtonListner {
     void buttonClicked (String s);
  }
  onButtonListner myButtonListner;
  ```
- в методе `onCreatView` прописываю возвращаемый в `Activity` макет

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nxtbtn, container, false); 
  }
  ```
- в методе `onAttach` привожу родительское `Activity` к интерфейсу

  ```
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);

      this.myButtonListner = (onButtonListner) context;
  }
  ```
- в родительской `Activity` имплементирую интерфейс и реализую его метод

  ```
  public class DescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment_nxtbtn.onButtonListner

  public void buttonClicked(String s) {

      //do something

  }
  ```

... и вот далее я пробовал реализовывать в методах фрагмента `onCreateView` и `onStart` непосредственно `onClickListner` и метод `onClick` но безуспешно.   Поведение приложения - макет формируется, кнопки отображаются, но при попытке нажатия приложение крашится.
***По логу ошибка***

> nullPointerException в строке вызова интерфейса
>   myButtonListner.buttonClicked("test");

(см ниже)

последняя реализация метода `onStart`

---

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //получаем родительское view

    View parentview = getView();

    //получаем из xml айди кнопок 

    ImageButton nextbtn = (ImageButton) parentview.findViewById(R.id.nxtbtn_imageButton_next);
    ImageButton prevbtn = (ImageButton) parentview.findViewById(R.id.nxtbtn_imageButton_prev);

    //создаем онклик листнер для кнопок и передаем в методе онклик значение кнопки в метод buttonclicked интерфейса

    View.OnClickListener myOnClickListner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       //вот тут nullPointerException

       myButtonListner.buttonClicked("test");

        }
    };

    //реализуем онкликлистнер на подключенной кнопке

    nextbtn.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListner);
```

### prevbtn.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListner);

**полный код родительского Activity**

```
package dev.eyesless.needmypuppy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class DescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment_nxtbtn.onButtonListner {

    public static final String GETBREEDID = "getbreedid";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

        //получаем ссылку на фрагмент breed description через создание его экземпляра - в этом фрагменте проблем нет(!)

        Fragment_description mydescription = (Fragment_description)getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_breed_description);

        //вызываем метод fragment_description чтобы передать ID отображаемого айтема

        mydescription.setBreedId((int)getIntent().getExtras().get("getbreedid"));
    }

       // реализация интерфейса фрагмента Fragment_nxtbtn - тут проблема (!)

    @Override
    public void buttonClicked(String s) {

// do something


    }
}
```

---

**полный код фрагмента**

```
package dev.eyesless.needmypuppy;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_nxtbtn extends Fragment {


    // реализуем интерфейс и его экземпляр

    static interface onButtonListner {
        void buttonClicked (String s);
    }
    onButtonListner myButtonListner;


    public Fragment_nxtbtn() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final View parentview = getView();

        ImageButton nextbtn = (ImageButton) parentview.findViewById(R.id.nxtbtn_imageButton_next);
        ImageButton prevbtn = (ImageButton) parentview.findViewById(R.id.nxtbtn_imageButton_prev);

         //создаем онклик листнер для кнопок и передаем в методе онклик значение кнопки в метод buttonclicked интерфейса

        View.OnClickListener myOnClickListner = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //    тут nullPointerException         
               myButtonListner.buttonClicked("test");

            }
        };

        //реализуем онкликлистнер на подключенной кнопке

        nextbtn.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListner);
        prevbtn.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListner);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nxtbtn, container, false);


    }

    //получаем на вход родительское активити и приводим его к типу интерфейса чтобы можно было вызвать метод интерфейса из активности

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.myButtonListner = (onButtonListner) context;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

API устройства/эмулятора какое?

`onAttach(Context context)` работает только для API23+, т.е. начиная с Android 6. Либо используйте `onAttach(Activity activity)` для версий ниже, либо используйте android.support.v4.app.Fragment из библиотеки поддержки.

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло! действительно, если заменить Context context на Activity activity все работает, но AndroidStudio помечает метод onAttach как @Deprecated, по этому я пошел по второму пути - поменял в блоке импорта import app.Fragment на import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: дополнительно - соответственно в родительской Activity искать данный фрагмент нужно не через FragmentManager, а через SupportFragmentManager: 'Fragment_nxtbtn mynxtbtn = (Fragment_nxtbtn) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_nxtbtn);'

Answer (score 1):

Если это не единственный клик, который нужно обрабатывать на активити, то заимплементьте на активити простой `OnClickListener` и так же повесьте его на кнопку в фрагменте и при клике в `OnclickListener` фрагмента делайте следующее: `((YourActivity)getActivity()).onClick(YourButton);`. В самой активити в `onClick(View view)` код вида:

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.your_button_id :
    //make what you need
    break;
}
```

Но вообще это плохая практика, активити не должно знать что на ней за фрагменты - они автономные единицы, активити только хост для них.

Comment: вот именно по этому я хочу использовать правильный путь - интерфейс

Comment: правильный путь это разделить всё на слои, понимая что fragment это элемент view слоя, с небольшими допущениями. Работа с бизнес логикой должна идти в слое model контактируя через presenter - это как частный случай MVC архитектуры, подвидов много но суть не меняется - всё длить на слои. Касательно этого случая можно сетить интерфейс в onCreteView через getActivity() и стирать в onDestroyView(), ну и активити, разумеется, проверяет всё это дело на null внутри себя.